# How to constructor in constructor

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I need add data in array Person. But program is not bug .
I do not know how to constructor  with type class in constructor  .

```
public Person[] personData =
{
    new Person {PersonId = 1, FirstName = "Adam", LastName ="Freeman",
        HomeAddress = { City = "SoKa" , Country = "Look" }  },
    new Person {PersonId = 2, FirstName = "Nhan", LastName ="Ga",
        HomeAddress = { City = "Dalat" , Country = "VungTau" } },
};
```

Declarations

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }

    public class Address
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
HomeAddress = new Person.Address{ City = "SoKa" , Country = "Look" }
```

instead of

```
HomeAddress = { City = "SoKa" , Country = "Look" }
```